# Create a new column based on row match and replace it with a new term

Tags: r

This is my data frame small part

```
  df <- dput(head(D1,20))
structure(list(PMID = c(1060744, 1617318, 1691132, 1691132, 1691132, 
1691132, 1691132, 1691134, 1691134, 1691134, 1691134, 1691134, 
1691134, 1691134, 1828453, 1828453, 1861532, 1861532, 2031969, 
2031969), Term = c("PRAVD", "Cyclophosphamide", "Daunorubicin", 
"Cytosine arabinoside", "Vincristine", "AMSA", "Azacytidine", 
"Ara-C", "Amsacrine", "-C", "5-azacytidine", "AZA", "Daunorubicin", 
"DNR/CD-Ara-C", "Mithramycin", "Hydroxyurea", "Retinol", "Retinol palmitate", 
"Cytosine arabinoside", "Daunorubicin"), Class = c("Chemical", 
"Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", 
"Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", 
"Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", 
"Chemical"), MESH = c("-", "MESH:D003520", "MESH:D003630", "MESH:D003561", 
"MESH:D014750", "MESH:D000677", "MESH:D001374", "MESH:D003561", 
"MESH:D000677", "MESH:D002244", "MESH:D001374", "MESH:D001379", 
"MESH:D003630", "-", "MESH:D008926", "MESH:D006918", "MESH:D014801", 
"MESH:C014794", "MESH:D003561", "MESH:D003630")), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), X2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), X3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), X4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 0), class = "col_spec"), row.names = c(7L, 
16L, 28L, 29L, 31L, 34L, 37L, 39L, 45L, 49L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
62L, 65L, 74L, 76L, 91L, 92L), class = "data.frame")
```

So as an example in this dataframe the Ara-C term has a MESH Term associated with it.

```
Ara-C Chemical MESH:D003561
```

But here this one downstream of the dataframe I have the same term but the MESH term is not annotated which is `MESH:D003561`

```
Ara-C Chemical -
```

Similarly I have another term where this "Fludarabine" has a MESH term

```
Ozogamicin Chemical MESH:C406061
```

but at another row this `Ozogamicin Chemical -`doesn't have the MESH term which is

```
MESH:C406061
```

Now I would like to add another column basically a new MESH column with updated MESH terms like wherever there is this `-` it should be replaced by its respective MESH term.

How do i do that.?

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do that by using the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)

# create unique correspondence between Term, Class and MESH
Class_Mesh <- df %>% 
    select(Term, Class, MESH) %>% 
    filter(MESH != "-") %>% 
    unique() %>% 
    rename(MESH_updated = MESH)

# join both tables, replacing MESH with updated MESH if == "-"
new_df <- df %>% 
    left_join(Class_Mesh) %>% 
    mutate(MESH = ifelse(MESH == "-", MESH_updated, MESH)) %>% 
    select(-MESH_updated)
```

First, you build a unique correspondence between your Term and Class columns and the MESH column. Then, join those tables and only change the MESH values that have a "-". Finally, drop the updated column.